# Excel text with values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible in Excel to have a cell show text that is different from its value?

I would like to have a a cell that has a value of $55.00, but only show the text "brief physical" in the cell.

Then I would like to be able to use that cell in a formula, using the 55.

For example:

My spread sheet top row a1= brief physical, b1= intermediate physical and c1= dot physical.

The value for a brief is $55.00, intermediate is $75 and dot is $ 60.00.

Can someone explain to me how to assign these cells the correct value, step by step please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign **A1** the *Custom Format* of:

"brief physical"

[image]

Notice that the formula bar shows the "true" value, but the cell displays the text.

Comment: You are amazing. You have just saved me about 2 hours of manually inputing hundreds of formulas.

Comment: @kimmie360 If this was you solution, please mark as answer.